# File upload does not work in Windows 10 edge browser

Tags: html, file-upload, microsoft-edge

The file upload function does not work in Windows 10 edge browser. It worked fine with other browsers.

**Code**

```
<input type="file" name="uploadField" />
```

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the Microsoft edge beta version. The browse function works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me for a while, then yesterday, it started to freeze up. I can break the debugger in the developer tools and it appears to be in an infinite loop inside jquery.

Comment: Update: it's not stuck in jquery. The loop seems to be in browserlink. I'll try to post the screen shot...